# Remove namespace from XML in Java

Tags: java, xml

I want to remove namespace from XML in Java. Can you pls guide on what needs to be done. Can use DOM parser but that would be a node by node parsing. I want to know if there is some code wherein all the namespace(`mig:`) can be removed from the entire XML.

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mig:menu-compare xmlns:mig="http://www..com/migration/" xmlns:xsi="http://www..org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www..com/migration">
    <mig:menu-info>
        <mig:menu type="ons" name="HRDM"/>
        <mig:menu type="ux" name="ARD"/>
    </mig:menu-info>
    <mig:field-details>
        <mig:fields existence="nonMap">
            <mig:field>
                <mig:field-type type="ons">
                    <mig:ui-field>funcCode</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT000204</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Function</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>Y</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
            <mig:field>
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:ui-field>submit</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FBT000000</mig:label>
                    <mig:section-structure></mig:section-structure>
                    <mig:form></mig:form>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
            <mig:field>
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:ui-field>cancel</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FBT000001</mig:label>
                    <mig:section-structure></mig:section-structure>
                    <mig:form></mig:form>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
        </mig:fields>
        <mig:fields existence="both">
            <mig:field name="rptDfnMsg.rptDfnInfo.gprRptNum">
                <mig:field-type type="ons">
                    <mig:control-type>Text Field</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>rptNum</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT006718</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Report No.</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>Y</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:control-type>FinTextInputWithSearcher</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>reportNo</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT005821</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Report No.</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>Y</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
            <mig:field name="rptDfnMsg.rptDfnInfo.gprRptDesc">
                <mig:field-type type="ons">
                    <mig:control-type>Desc. Label</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>rptDesc</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label></mig:label>
                    <mig:mandatory>N</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:control-type>FinTextInput</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>desc</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT000690</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Description</mig:label-desc>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>

        </mig:fields>
        <mig:fields existence="ons">
            <mig:field name="rptDfnMaster.gprRptDesc">
                <mig:field-type type="ons">
                    <mig:ui-field>rptDesc</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT002771</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Description</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>Y</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
            <mig:field name="rptDfnMaster.gprRptType.code">
                <mig:field-type type="ons">
                    <mig:ui-field>rptType</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT007124</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Report Type</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>Y</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>

        </mig:fields>
        <mig:fields existence="ux">
            <mig:field name="rptDfnMsg.rptDfnInfo.gprRptType.code">
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:ui-field>reporttype</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT005818</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Report Type</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>Y</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
            <mig:field name="rptDfnMsg.rptDfnInfo.gprRptConsolFlg">
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:control-type>FinComboBox</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>printRep</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT011541</mig:label>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
         </mig:fields>
    </mig:field-details>
</mig:menu-compare>
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple String replacement with regular expressions?

Comment: Would string.removeAll("mig:") be an option?

Comment: Stop suggesting regex for tasks like that, nothing good will come out of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Use an XML parser or XSLT to remove namespaces. There are a lot of options out there and the right choice depend on a number of factors we can not determine for you.

Comment: Why? It's legal XML. If you're using standard XML tools they should all understand it, and if you're not you should be. One obvious solution would be to use XSLT and declare the namespace as the default. But the purpose remains obscure.

Comment: Able to proceed by using XSLT

Answer (score 13):

You can use xslt for that. Try

**removeNs.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Sample.java**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("removeNs.xslt"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text = new StreamSource(new File("data.xml"));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
        System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex can be used for more information refer [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/XML/Removeallthexmlnamespacesxmlnsattributesinthexmlstring.htm)

```
public static string RemoveAllXmlNamespace(string xmlData)
        {
            string xmlnsPattern = "\\s+xmlns\\s*(:\\w)?\\s*=\\s*\\\"(?<url>[^\\\"]*)\\\"";
            MatchCollection matchCol = Regex.Matches(xmlData, xmlnsPattern);

            foreach (Match m in matchCol)
            {
                xmlData = xmlData.Replace(m.ToString(), "");
            }
            return xmlData;
        }
   }
```

You can find a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661154/how-do-i-remove-namespaces-from-xml-using-java-dom)

Regex can be painful. you can also use this api (dom) to get rid of all namespaces.[refer this](http://blog.avisi.nl/2013/07/24/java-stripping-namespaces-from-xml-using-dom/)

```
 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    ...

    /**
     * Recursively renames the namespace of a node.
     * @param node the starting node.
     * @param namespace the new namespace. Supplying <tt>null</tt> removes the namespace.
     */
    public static void renameNamespaceRecursive(Node node, String namespace) {
        Document document = node.getOwnerDocument();
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            document.renameNode(node, namespace, node.getNodeName());
        }
        NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); ++i) {
            renameNamespaceRecursive(list.item(i), namespace);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is **always** terrible advice to use regex for XML parsing. It simply can not be done. Using this code you will certainly run into problems, e.g. suddenly you have the string "xmlns" somewhere as text in your XML.